# Facebook SDK integration in iOS shows Error "Receiver 'Facebook' for class message is a forward declaration"

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using `Facebook-iOS-SDK` for integrating the Facebook in my app. (The SDK is installed using cocoaPods) It always showing an error `"Facebook.h not found"` error when I try to import the Facebook.h class.

And I tried the `@class Facebook;` in my view controller's .h class and created the Facebook class instance. But i can't call any method of that class, when trying to call a method, it shows an error `" Receiver 'Facebook' for class message is a forward declaration"`

Is there any way to use the methods in the Facebook.h class.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: use #import < Facebook/Facebook.h>

Comment: BHASKAR no luck :-( It also shows the same error "Facebook/Facebook.h file not found"

Answer (score 1):

Hi Neenu if you are using OS X Yosemite, try updating the command line tools and reinstalling pod file also you can try to set the path of Xcode using this command :

sudo xcode-select --switch "/Applications/Xcode6-Beta6.app/Contents/Developer".

If this doesn't solve the issue there is problem with pod file installation.Hope it helps

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @lord Zsolt My reputation is low thats why had to answer

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, it's ok then :)

Comment: what is the name of your podfile?